# How can I compile my project in C++ so it will create on my hard disk a .dll file of my project to use it later with another program?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

This is the main code:

```
// DSPlayer.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DSPlayer.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include "PlayerClass.h"


/********* GLOBAL VARIABLES **********/
HINSTANCE g_hInst;
HWND g_hDialogWindow;

// pointer to my PlayerClass obejct
PlayerClass *g_PlayerObject = NULL;



/******** FUNCTION DECLARATIONS ******/
BOOL CALLBACK DlgDSPlayerProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);




int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;

    HICON iconLarge = NULL;

    InitCommonControls();

    g_hInst = hInstance;

    g_hDialogWindow = CreateDialog(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DLGDSPLAYER), NULL, (DLGPROC)DlgDSPlayerProc);

    // this will set the icon for my player
    iconLarge = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICONLARGE));

    if (iconLarge)
    {
        SendMessage(g_hDialogWindow, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)iconLarge);
    }


    // Initialize the COM library
    CoInitialize(NULL);


    if (!g_hDialogWindow)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Dialog creation failed! Aborting..", "Error", MB_OK);
        return -1;
    }

    ShowWindow(g_hDialogWindow, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(g_hDialogWindow);

    if (g_PlayerObject == NULL)
    {
        // create the player object
        g_PlayerObject = new PlayerClass();

        if (g_PlayerObject)
        {
            g_PlayerObject->Initialise(g_hDialogWindow);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, "Error creating player object", "Error", MB_OK);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    // standard message loop
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!IsDialogMessage(g_hDialogWindow, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }


    return msg.wParam;
}



BOOL CALLBACK DlgDSPlayerProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    bool handled = false;

    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
                return TRUE;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch ( LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case IDC_OPENFILE:
                    handled = true;
                    ///SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_NOWPLAYING), "You selected Play File..");
                    g_PlayerObject->OpenFileDialog();
                    break;

                case IDC_PLAYPAUSE:
                    handled = true;
                    //SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_NOWPLAYING), "You selected Pause");
                    g_PlayerObject->DoPlayPause();
                    break;

                case IDC_STOP:
                    handled = true;
                    //SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_NOWPLAYING), "You selected Stop");
                    g_PlayerObject->DoStop();
                    break;

                case IDC_EXIT:
                    handled = true;
                    free(g_PlayerObject);
                    EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                    break;
                    //handled = true;
            }

        case WM_TIMER:
            g_PlayerObject->DoTimerStuff();
            break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
            //MessageBox(NULL, "got close", "info", MB_OK);
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        case WM_GRAPHNOTIFY:
            handled = true;
            g_PlayerObject->EventReceiver();
            break;




/*      case WM_CLOSE:
            CleanUp(hDlg);
            handled = true;
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            break;
*/
    }

    return handled;

}
```

It's not my project.

Now I went to the project properties and under General>Target Extension its: .dll
And under General>Configuration Type> its: Dynamic Library (.dll)

But when I'm doing doing to my project Build>Build Solution
I can't find any .dll files the the Debug directory.

I'm using Visual Studio `C++` Express 2010.

What am I missing here?

OutPut Results:

```
>------ Build started: Project: DSPlayer, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(298,5): warning MSB8004: Intermediate Directory does not end with a trailing slash.  This build instance will add the slash as it is required to allow proper evaluation of the Intermediate Directory.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(299,5): warning MSB8004: Output Directory does not end with a trailing slash.  This build instance will add the slash as it is required to allow proper evaluation of the Output Directory.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(990,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(D:\DSPlayer\DSPlayer\.\Debug\DSPlayer.dll) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (D:\DSPlayer\DSPlayer\Debug\DSPlayer.exe). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(991,5): warning MSB8012: TargetExt(.dll) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (.exe). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
1>  DSPlayer.vcxproj -> D:\DSPlayer\DSPlayer\.\Debug\DSPlayer.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

[image]

This are the two warnings:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(990,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(D:\DSPlayer\DSPlayer\.\Debug\DSPlayer.dll) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (D:\DSPlayer\DSPlayer\Debug\DSPlayer.exe). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(991,5): warning MSB8012: TargetExt(.dll) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (.exe). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
```

How and where do i have to fix this warnings ? can someone upload here a screenshot to show me how and where to do it ?

Comment: Assuming that there are no build errors - have you checked that a) you are actually building the Debug configuration and b) the output directory is where you think it is.

Comment: I just added to my question the output im getting when compiling it. Im getting some warning im not sure why. Still i can't see and .dll file/s

Comment: I'd fix those warnings. Add the trailing slash to the intermediate and output directories, then rebuild

Comment: Now im not getting any errors or warnings and still no .dll file/s. I just added to my question an image screenshot of my project properties general area settings.

Comment: Have you searched the folders for the dll?

Comment: I have the project here: http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?mpmd8bu5u10y8o1

Very small project im using most with c# not c++ so maybe someone can download the project and fix it or look for the problemn why it's not creating a .dll file?


If i change it back to create exe in the project properties i see that it's creating a new .exe file of the project/solution but when it's on .dll the settings nothing.



Thanks.

Comment: ChrisF i did search for it in everyhwere i cuold think of. Nothing. Maybe someone can download and try it and maybe find why when creating .exe of it it's working good but when trying to create a .dll nothing. Maybe the one who created the project did something in the code or somehow that prevent from creating dll's ?

Comment: Yes i searched for the .dll in the same directory where it created the .exe before. This is strange.

Comment: Now i see two warnings with the dll file/s and the exe file/s and im not sure how to fix it. Can someone pelase add here a screenshot or explain to me step by step where should i fix this directories things and how ? Can't figure out how ot fix this warnings.

Comment: I added the two warnings to the question !

Comment: What you are doing makes no sense to me, you are taking source for building a windows application and trying to build a DLL from it. What do you hope to accomplish from this? Even if you were to succeed to build the DLL, I doubt you would be able to accomplish what you intend...Perhaps it would help if you would explain what you want to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

write .\Debug in output directory and intermediate directory and then click clean and 
 build then it generate .exe files even if this warning occur

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: i answer it iam not ask